# Visual Studio 2019 Interrumpe el Monitoreo de mi Aplicación sin emitir errores!!! y no cierra la aplicacion

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compilar, depuración, vs2019

### Estoy creando una aplicación de Escritorio usando:

*C#/winform y IDE VS2019 Community y .Net 4.5.2 framework
Todo esta en una sola Solución/Proyecto*

### Que intento que haga mi aplicación (explicación conceptual):

1. La idea era crear una aplicación que lea un XML, dicho XML tiene una lista de URLS (De Internet y de la Red Local).
2. De las URLS leídas hace una prueba de conexión e intenta extrae el Icono de la web (favicon):

> *Desde Internet (implementa la api de gogole)*
> ***Ejemplo 1:*** https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=32&domain_url=https://www.google.com/
> ***Resultado:*** Recoge el Icono; si se dan WebException las captura y asigna un icono por defecto.

> *Desde la Red Local (evalúa directamente si existe la url del icono)*
> ***Ejemplo 1:*** http://avisistema-3.pro/favicon.ico
> ***Resultado:*** Recoge el Icono; si se dan WebException las captura y asigna un icono por defecto.

3. Llegado a este punto; la aplicación genera por cada URL un PictureBox con un evento Click.
4. Al hacer click en el PictureBox; se abre un Form en donde recibo la URL y Cargo un Control Hidratado con la librería CefSharp, que me permite Cargar la URL como un WebView, en un subproceso creado por CefSharp; a partir de este punto el usuario interactuar con la web y con el subproceso que ejecuta CefSharp.

### ¿Cuál es el problema que tengo?:

Sucede que al llegar al punto 3 antes mencionado (sin hacer click, ni nada), el VS2019 Cambia por algún motivo que desconozco.

### ¿Qué Cambios tiene el VS2019?:

> **Nota Importante:** el monitoreo de VS2019 que me refiero, es al de hacer un stop en cada break point que he agregado en el código en el
> margen izquierdo que permite evaluar y depurar en tiempo real las
> variables y los datos que contienen, en mi caso en el punto 3 tengo
> varios y el VS2019 al haber detenido el monitoreo simplemente no me
> deja ver estos break point, hasta la segunda corrida …

Aunque la aplicación sigue Ejecutándose; el VS2019 sale del monitoreo de la misma.
Al Ver el Log de depuración me sale los siguientes mensajes:

```
'Avisistema 3 Desktop.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'Avisistema 3 Desktop.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): 'D:\Personal\Avisistema 3\nuevo\Avisistema 3 Desktop\bin\Debug\Avisistema 3 Desktop.exe' cargado. Símbolos cargados.
'Avisistema 3 Desktop.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Avisistema 3 Desktop.exe): 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'Avisistema 3 Desktop.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Avisistema 3 Desktop.exe): 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'Avisistema 3 Desktop.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Avisistema 3 Desktop.exe): 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'Avisistema 3 Desktop.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Avisistema 3 Desktop.exe): 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'Avisistema 3 Desktop.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Avisistema 3 Desktop.exe): 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'Avisistema 3 Desktop.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Avisistema 3 Desktop.exe): 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll' cargado. Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
'Avisistema 3 Desktop.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Avisistema 3 Desktop.exe): 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_es_b77a5c561934e089\System.resources.dll' cargado. El módulo se compiló sin símbolos.
Excepción producida: 'System.Net.WebException' en System.dll
Excepción producida: 'System.Net.WebException' en System.dll
Excepción producida: 'System.Net.WebException' en System.dll
Excepción producida: 'System.Net.WebException' en System.dll
'Avisistema 3 Desktop.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Avisistema 3 Desktop.exe): 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\mscorlib.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_es_b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.resources.dll' cargado. El módulo se compiló sin símbolos.
El programa '[24132] Avisistema 3 Desktop.exe' terminó con código 0 (0x0).
```

### Ilustración:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Que ayuda Necesito/Espero de las personas que lee este Post?:

A. Una Explicación detallada (en español) de cómo solucionar este Mensaje específicamente desde VS2019:

```
'Avisistema 3 Desktop.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Avisistema 3 Desktop.exe): 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\mscorlib.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_es_b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.resources.dll' cargado. El módulo se compiló sin símbolos.
```

B. Que alguien me indique si es normal y correcto que las `WebException` que estoy capturando salgan en el log de depuración:

Excepción producida: `'System.Net.WebException'` en System.dll

C. Una Explicación detallada (en español) del por qué el Visual Studio detiene el monitoreo de la ejecución de la aplicación en el punto 3; sin cerrar la aplicación o emitir algún error.

### Pruebas Realizadas:

Para el punto C que es el más importan en mi caso, he hecho esto:

I. he cerrado el visual studio y con el administrador he validado que no haya nada relacionado ejecutándose.
II. Abrí el proyecto
III. le di play resultado:

> A. la Aplicación se ejecutó.
>     B. al llegar la aplicación al
> punto 3, automáticamente VS2019 Cambio: emitió los mensajes descritos
> en el post que se ven en el log y dejo de monitorear la
> aplicación.
>     C. la Aplicación continúo ejecutándose, no se cerró
> ni se interrumpió su ejecución (no hice nada con esta ventana de la
> aplicación).

IV. sin cerrar la ventana anterior que quedo abierta, el VS2019 me permitió darle play nuevamente resultado:

> A. la Aplicación se ejecutó nuevamente, permitiéndome tener 2 al
> mismo tiempo.
>     B. al llegar la aplicación al punto 3, Aquí si
> continuo el monitorear la aplicación.
>     C. tengo 2 ventanas de la
> misma aplicación.

### Nueva duda:

Porque la segunda vez que doy play el VS2019 no tuvo el mismo comportamiento?
**Nota:** no entiendo que está pasando con el VS2019, amaneció troll.

## Imágenes de Interés:

#### Estructura del proyecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Configuración de compilado y Depuración:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Paquetes externos instalados no relacionados con el Problema mencionados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Resultado del Compilado en el directorio debug:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]